# Angular 11 - ng serve taking almost 7 minutes with Firebase/Firestore/AngularMaterial

Tags: firebase, angular-material, angular11

I have recently started a new angular project with the intention of trying out firebase authentication and firestore. I have also added in some angular material components, as well as a theme. I am not sure exactly when the ng serve started getting very slow but my last build took 406959ms -> 6.7 minutes. This doesn't really help productivity. (This time also seems to be quite consistent)

I have tried setting source map to false but that doesn't seem to help. Running with 'ng serve --verbose --no-progress' there are obviously more logs but I can't seem to see what is obviously wrong (I may just not know what I am looking for?). I have also tried to rollback the Angular CLI as well as delete node modules and re-install.

There are some warnings from DedupeModuleResolvePlugin, but no other warnings or errors, and it does eventually compile and run.

Any pointers as to what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any resolution? I am experiencing the same lag with the same stack.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should update to Angular version to 11.1.0 which has fix for this issue

`ng update @angular/cli@^11.1.0 @angular/core@^11.1.0`

2. In angular.json file, You can try to set these options under configurations-

"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,

[image]